# I need help getting a replacement grip shifter for a 9 speed rear derailleur

Tags: derailleur-rear, sram, grip-shifter

UPDATE: pictures of the rear derailleur at the bottom...

I have a 2003 bianchi strada that I love to pieces and works great. it is now 19 years old and I've quite worn away all of the rubber grip on the grip shifters. I wanted to replace them, but there's not much in the way of parts I can find, I was hoping somebody could help me. I don't know a lot about bike parts, I just like to ride.

There's 3 chain rings in front, and 9 gears in back, and I love my grip shifter.
The original shifters say "SRAM 7.0" on them. (see pictures)

[image: original shifter]

[image: other side]

[image: other other side]

I sent a note to SRAM support and they recommended "07A SL Centra Twister set." So I bought this, put it on my bike, and the front shifter is fine, but the rear doesn't have the cable travel to cover all 9 gears. It will only shift between 6 gears.

[image: new front shifter is fine]

[image: new rear shifter doesn't have enough travel in the cable to cover all 9 gears]

I should have realized that the display for the new set didn't travel as far as the round-the-grip display on the original set.

Anyway, I don't know where to look, does there exist a 9-gear grip shifter where the display goes around the handle that would have enough cable travel to cover the 9 gears on my derailleur? The rear derailleur is a shimano something or other, but it's so old and covered in grease and dirt that if there was a part number, it's long gone now.
if sending a picture would help, lemme know I can do that.

[image: new part number]

so I was wrong, it isn't a shimano derailleur on the back, I misremembered and apparently didn't look closely...

[image: rear pic 1]

[image: rear pic 2]

[image: rear pic 3]

Specs for 2003 Bianchi Strada from BikePedia: (Armand edit)

[image]

Comment: as you're invested, you may as well buy the matching sram rear derailleur which will be X4 or X5 1:1 actuation. they are not expensive

Comment: interesting thought, it just seems a bit heavy handed to throw out the bathtub because the new water I got is incompatible. I guess worst case I can do that, but I'd rather just get a new shifter.

Comment: You have already replaced the shifters so you've spent the money. I argue it makes less sense to buy yet another set of shifters.

Comment: Also for 9sp the 1:1 shifting actuation is a notable improvement in feel and adjustment, so it's not a wasted modification

Comment: This is a great example of where using heat shrink might work well

Comment: I'm happy to buy another set of shifters, I just don't know what part to buy because clearly there are 9 speed shifters and there are 9 speed shifters.

Comment: how/where/why would heat shrink work? you lost me. can't imagine a way heat shrink would apply here.

Comment: The display is geared so doesn't need to travel so far as the old markings

Comment: @stu heat shrink comes in all sorts of sizes - a short length of 35 or 40 or 45mm heatshink could wrap around the worn area of the old shifter, and be shrunk down by a hot air gun (flame/fire doesn't work well on larger sizes)  Then it would form a new skin.   This came up recently in the "melted grips" question at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/87050/suggestions-for-replacing-melted-grips

Comment: ahhh, I see, I wasn't sure what purpose you were getting at for using the heatshrink

Answer (score 3):

If you like the ergonomics and feel of the new Centera shifters you got, the play is probably to get rid of the 1:1 SRAM 7.0 rear derailleur and replace it any of many Shimano-compatible mountain 7/8/9 "2:1" units that are compatible with it.  The 7.0 RD was a fine part but at 19 years old on a heavily used bike, it's going to be showing age in terms of performance. You could always just look for vintage/NOS 1:1 9-speed shifters if you absolutely had to keep your 7.0 RD going.

SRAM did offer replacement rubber for their nicer Gripshift models and your 7.0 was covered. Those were always under-utilized by shops and the public so what you need might still be attainable NOS. I see from perusing the [2003 SRAM spare parts catalog](https://www.disraeligears.co.uk/site/sram_-_spare_parts_list_2003_page_6.html) that you appear to have the 'half-pipe' version of the 7.0 gripshift with fully indexed left and if so your SRAM part number at the time was 200-864 for the right grip and 200-867 for the left.

Answer (score 2):

You have fallen into the trap of replacing your old shifters, designed to work with SRAM 1:1 derailleurs (aka ESP) with current shifters designed to work with Shimano's 1:2 ratio classic rear derailleur.

There are no decent quality 9sp gripshifters currently produced even by SRAM, who make a whole range of gripshifters for most of their own MTB groups. Some spares are available or you could downgrade your shifters, cassette and chain to SRAM 8sp compatible with your derailleur.

Unless you want to go to 8 speed or change to SRAM X4 triggers, you'll have to buy a Shimano rear derailleur. It is not an expensive modification but won't win you much performance improvement.

Comment: Although to be honest your new shifters should pull way too much cable for a shimano derailleur so you'd better photo that too so we can see what you've done. it doesn't need to be clean to be identified. @stu

Comment: turns out I was wrong and it wasn't a shimano derailleur, which explains that. So... can you point me to something that explains this SRAM 1:1 system since it's starting to look like I'm going to end up buying a new derailleur.

Comment: Ok, what you have there *ought* to work. are you sure you pulled enough cable through (cable slack in 9th) and have set the L/H screws properly? @stu

Comment: Yeah I adjusted it both ways so that I could reach first or 9th but in so doing I couldn't get to the other end. But I'll go back and see if there's some more knobs to turn or if I kinked the cable over something. Thanks for the confirmation that it should work.

Comment: Did you say to SRAM service you had a Shimano derailleur by any chance? @stu

Comment: So updated with better info

Comment: yes I did, because that's what I thought at the time. I sent them the same pictures I posted here and they said the same thing "that shifter should work with the existing derailleur"

Comment: @stu well, it makes sense you got the wrong shifters then. All your gear is 20 years old so I doubt any of the tech crew have been working that long. The only easy to identify part was your rear derailleur which is definitively an ESP/1:1 derailleur

Comment: okay so I just found a nice description of what the 1:1 and 1:2 ratios mean. great. but since I lose 2 gears (I fiddled with it somore more and got from gears 1 to 7 at the ends of the grip shift) that would imply a 1:1.7 or so kinda ratio, or the grip shift just doesn't have the proper total cable travel for my rear derailleur. the sram guy was able to identify the era of the late 90's for the part, but I guess that doesn't mean he knows how it's set up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a rear derailleur compatible with your Shimano-style shifters would be something like a Shimano RD-R3000 Sora Rear Derailleur - 9 Speed - medium cage. The medium cage (vs short cage) is important as that provides capacity to take up the slack of your 20-tooth small vs large front chainring difference (assuming yours has 28/38/48 chainrings).

That RD is easily available in early 2023 from the usual reputable online US dealers; I would avoid purchasing this or any similar derailleur on ebay, as many of those are fakes.

Of course, letting your local bike shop find and sell you a compatible derailleur would help you establish a business relationship that would likely be helpful with future issues. A good LBS will have access to all sorts of older parts not easily found by "civilians".

Comment: But of course it would be cleaner to still use SRAM as the rear cable route and final outer casing are shorter than Shimano. What a pickle!

Comment: this shouldn't be this difficult. :-)